# Proving equivalence of two definitions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Hi all I am intersted in proving the equivalence of the following two definitions of pseudomontoncity:

Let $V$ be a reflexive Banach space and $K \subset V$ closed and convex.

**Definition 1:**
$A: V \rightarrow V^{*}$ is pseudomonotone if  $A \text{ is bounded}$ and $$u_{n} \rightharpoonup u \text{ and } \limsup\limits_{{n \rightarrow \infty}}\langle A(u_{n}), u_{n}-u\rangle \leq 0 ~ \Longrightarrow ~ \forall v \in V: \langle A(u), u-v\rangle \leq \liminf\limits_{{n \rightarrow \infty}}\langle A(u_{n}), u_{n}-v \rangle.$$

**Defintion 2:** $A$ is pseudomonotone if $A~~\text{is bounded}$ and $$ u_{n} \rightharpoonup u \text{ in } V,~~u_{n} \in K ~~\text{ and }~~ \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\langle A(u_{n}),u_{n}-u \rangle \leq 0$$ implies $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \langle A(u_{n}), u_{n}-u \rangle = 0~~ \text{  and }~~ A(u_{n}) \rightharpoonup A(u) \text{  in  } V^{*}. $$

The implication Definition 2 $\implies$ Definition 1 is easy to show. I am interested in the other implication Definition 1 $\implies$ Definition 2. Does anyone have any idea how to prove this?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Taking $v = u$ in definition 1, we find

$$\langle A(u), u-u\rangle = 0 \leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n), u_n - u\rangle \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n), u_n - u\rangle \leqslant 0,$$

which shows the first part,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n), u_n - u\rangle = 0,$$

of definition 2. Using that, we obtain that for all $v\in V$ we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\langle A(u), u-v\rangle &\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n), u_n - v\rangle\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \bigl( \langle A(u_n), u_n-u\rangle + \langle A(u_n), u-v\rangle\bigr)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n),u_n-u\rangle + \liminf_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n), u-v\rangle\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n), u-v\rangle.
\end{aligned}$$

In other words, for all $w\in V$, we have - setting $v = u-w$ -

$$\langle A(u),w\rangle \leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n),w\rangle.\tag{1}$$

The same inequality for $-w$ yields

$$\begin{aligned}
-\langle A(u),w\rangle &= \langle A(u),-w\rangle\\
&\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n),-w\rangle\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \bigl(-\langle A(u_n),w\rangle\bigr)\\
&= -\limsup_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n),w\rangle,
\end{aligned}$$

i.e.

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n),w\rangle \leqslant \langle A(u),w\rangle.\tag{2}$$

Together, $(1)$ and $(2)$ yield

$$\langle A(u),w\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle A(u_n),w\rangle\tag{3}$$

for all $w\in V$, i.e. $A(u_n) \rightharpoonup A(u)$ in $V^\ast$ (since $V$ is reflexive, hence the weak and weak$^\ast$ topologies coincide on $V^\ast$). That is the second part of definition 2, and we have shown that an operator that is pseudomonotone according to definition 1 is also pseudoomonotone according to definition 2.

Comment: Very nice proof. I am just wondering, why we need the set $K$ in the second definition. Did you use that?

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit I don't know what role $K$ plays. And it seems that something is missing, for choosing $K = \varnothing$ or $K = \{0\}$ makes definition 2 say that every bounded operator is pseudomonotone. (Didn't notice that when I wrote the answer.) But since $K$ only is used to restrict the sequences considered in definition 2, it's only pertinent for a proof of "def. 2 $\implies$ def. 1". It could be that def. 2 is used to define pseudomonotonicity for bounded operators $A \colon K \to V^{\ast}$, and then restricting to sequences $(u_n)$ in $K$ in definition 1 too would be natural.

Comment: Then we have the equivalence, and the proof would be the same up to a mention of the restriction $u_n \in K$. Since definition 2 as written doesn't say anything (except boundedness) about the behaviour of $A$ outside $K$, I think it's indeed about $A \colon K \to V^{\ast}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. I think you are right. Since I am only interested in the case $(1) \Longrightarrow (2)$, I wont have problems with that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Niklas As a side note, since you aksed about the role of $K$: In our lecture, we have to prove the following statement, which didn't have anything to do with this $K$ and works excatly like the answer above: Let $A: V \to V^*$ a bounded operator and $V$ be a real reflexive separable Banach space. Then $A$ is pseudomonotone if and only if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n , u \rangle \le 0$ implies $A u_n \rightharpoonup A u$ and $\langle A u_n, u_n \rangle \to \langle A u,u\rangle$ In our definition of pseudomonotnicity we didn't require $A$ to be bounded.